# g++ gcc include files not found

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++, g++

I have posted on another site, so hopefully this isn't cross posting:

I have a few versions of gcc and g++ on my Ubuntu 16.04 which i select with alternative config. When compiling a very simple source the compiler can't find the headers.(stddef.h: No such file or directory)

Upon investigation the gcc installations don't have a full directory, for example:

usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 has an include directory with cc1.exe

whilst:

usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7 had no include directory and no cc1.exe (just a cc1plus.exe)

I have re-installed 4.7 but can't seem to get it to be a complete installation ,any help?

Thanks

Emma

Answer (score 1):

You can see what packages provide these components using `dpkg -S` e.g.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/cc1 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include
cpp-4.7: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/cc1
libgcc-4.7-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include
```

Both `cpp-4.7` and `libgcc-4.7-dev` should have been installed as dependencies of `gcc-4.7` however it's possible that the files have been manually deleted - try re-intstalling those packages i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall cpp-4.7 libgcc-4.7-dev
```